# all variables from url

Tags: php, get

I have a code like that:

```
session_start();

$user = $_GET['user'];
$mode = $_GET['mode'];
$id1 = $_GET['id1'];
$id2 = $_GET['id2'];
$id3 = $_GET['id3'];
$id4 = $_GET['id4'];
$id5 = $_GET['id5'];
$id6 = $_GET['id6'];
$id7 = $_GET['id7'];
$id8 = $_GET['id8'];

$dep= $mode;
switch ($dep)
{
    case "3m":
        $dep = "Text 1";
        break;
    case "all":
        $dep = "More text";
        break;
    default:
        $dep = "Text1";
}
```

There are more other cases. I think I will have more id's and cases soon. Is there a simpler way to get all id's from URL push them into PHP code for evaluating?

I have found a code `foreach`:

```
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
        echo  'key is: <b>' . $key . '</b>, value is: <b>' .$value. '</b><br />';
    }
```

And it gets all variables from URL, but how to change the code in order to have it like this:

```
$variable = $_GET['variable'];
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Look into using form arrays. if you set up form fields with input_name[] then you can just loop through them on server side.

Comment: Are you looking to place the value in a variable with the name of the value? Why not just use the array for whatever it is you intend to do?

Comment: I will certainly look through form arrays, thnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood correctly and you want all GET variables to be actual variables you can use, there's a function [extract](http://fi.php.net/extract) to do that.

However, as noted in the documentation:

> Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (i.e. $_GET,
>   $_FILES, etc.). If you do, for example if you want to run old code
>   that relies on register_globals temporarily, make sure you use one of
>   the non-overwriting flags values such as EXTR_SKIP and be aware that
>   you should extract in the same order that's defined in variables_order
>   within the php.ini.

So basically you should not do this unless you have good reasons, and be careful if you do as to not overwrite any existing values.

However, if your alternative is to do this:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $$key=$value;
}
```

then extract is certainly better, as a) you can set it to not overwrite any existing variables, and b) you can have a prefix, so those imported variables can be distinguished. Like this:

```
extract ( $_GET, EXTR_SKIP);
```

For $user, $mode, $id which don't overwrite anything, or

```
extract ( $_GET, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'user_input' );
```

for $user_input_mode, $user_input_user, $user_input_id etc.

Comment: So I will not use it :) but thnks, I will familiarize this function

Comment: @T_5 the warnings are not strictly about this function, but about the approach in general! using the function with EXTR_SKIP is *safer* than the answer you've just accepted as it doesn't overwrite current variables and you can have them in a namespace.

Comment: thnks for warning, so you think your approach is good (the one with extract with EXTR_SKIP) or get the variables through form arrays or maybe use another way? I need to get variables which will be chosen by a user and push them into code, some is PHP, some MySQL query's (which are dependent on those variables) and then do some charts, results.

Comment: @T_5 I think my approach is better than the alternative and matches your requirement best. If it were up to me I would stick to what you originally have, but with your requirements, I think this is the best I can think of.

Comment: With your approach I have another idea what to do with my variables, so your solution is more then my requirements, thnks.

Answer (score 2):

Use arrays, that's exactly what they're for. Name the parameters in the URL like:

```
id[]=1&id[]=2&...
```

Then `$_GET['id']` is an array which you can easily loop through.

*Many ids* means you're looking for an *array of ids*, not id1, id2, id3 etc. An array allows you to access them virtually the same way as `$id[1]`, `$id[2]` etc, but without the headache of needing to herd hundreds of independent variables.

There's also no need to assign each value from `$_GET` into its own variable, you can use those values directly from `$_GET`. They're not getting any better by assigning them into individual variables.

Comment: that won't probably help with `user`, `mode` etc though. If those would be crammed into the same variable it would be actually worse than just iterating `$_GET`.

Comment: It doesn't need to, there's only one of each. This is specially about `id1`, `id2` etc.

Comment: It is a good way, but I will have more different names (not only id[]), so this won't help, but thnks :)

Comment: @deceze "all variables from url" says the subject, not just ids

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIDs()
{ 
    $ids = array();

    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
       foreach($_GET['id'] as $key => $value)
       {
          $ids[$key] = $value;
       }
    }
   return $ids;
}
```

If you can get your URL to send an array of `id` GET parameters to a PHP script you can just parse the `$_GET['id']` array in the above function, assuming the URI looks like `?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3`

```
$ids = getIDs();
```

Comment: Uhm... you can replace that loop with `$ids = $_GET['id']`.

Comment: @deceze I'm trying to show him how not to throw a warning if `id` is non-existent in the URI.

Comment: I'm saying you can replace *the loop*. You can leave the `isset`. You're transferring all keys and values from one array into another array... which means you're doing a complicated version of `$arr1 = $arr2`.

Comment: @deceze very true, didn't realize that.

Answer (score -1):

You can write

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $$key=$value;
    }
```

this will assign every key name as a varibale.

Comment: simple and fast, thnks :)

Comment: don't do this. It will overwrite any matching variable names in code, allowing anyone to inject any variables. Using the extract I linked is better, if you need to do this.

Comment: eis can you suggest some useful solution then ? according to question .

Comment: @BhawaniShankarMahapatra my suggestion is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19535711/365237)

Comment: OK, for me both ways will work, but with eis approach I can do more with my variables, that is why I am choosing his solution. Thnks BhawaniShankarMahapatra for your work.